# Convert txt to json file

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have a text file, need to convert that into JSON, please help

```
RULE_NAME{
    RULE 1
        SOURCE
        DESTINAION
        PORT
        POROTCOL
    RULE 2
        SOURCE
        DESTINAION
        PORT
        POROTCOL
    RULE 3
        ....
}
```

Need json format to be like this

```
Local{
 01
    SOURCE : SAG
    DESTINAION : any
    PORT :02
    POROTCOL: icmp 
 04
    SOURCE : SAG
    DESTINAION :any
    PORT: any
    POROTCOL : tcp
}
bk1-2-internal{
 02
    SOURCE : any
    DESTINAION : SoftLY
    PORT :any
    POROTCOL: any 
 28
    SOURCE : 119.111.126.115/18
    DESTINAION :129.37.164.74/30
    PORT: 112
    POROTCOL : udpt
}
```

My text file looks like this:

```
>Local = 01 : SAG = any = 02 = tcp
>Local = 04 : SAG = any = any = tcp
>bk1-2-internal = 2 : any = SoftLY = any = any
>bk1-2-internal = 28 : 119.111.126.115/18 = 129.37.164.74/30 = 112 = udpt
```

Goes upto 200 more lines with same format

i tried the code below but does not get expected structure. please check and assist in getting expected output, please feel free to contact at your own space, need to close this by today, please help

```
#filename = '/home/AY.txt'
  
import json 
  
  
# the file to be converted 
filename = '/home/ay/txt'
  
# resultant dictionary 
dict1 = {} 
  
# fields in the sample file  
fields =['name', 'source', 'destination', 'port' 'protocol'] 
  
with open(filename) as fh: 
      
  
      
    # count variable for employee id creation 
    l = 1
      
    for line in fh: 
          
        # reading line by line from the text file 
        description = list( line.strip().split(None, 4)) 
          
        # for output see below 
        print(description)  
          
        # for automatic creation of id for each employee 
        sno =' '+str(l) 
      
        # loop variable 
        i = 0
        # intermediate dictionary 
        dict2 = {} 
        while i<len(fields): 
              
                # creating dictionary for each employee 
                dict2[fields[i]]= description[i] 
                i = i + 1
                  
        # appending the record of each employee to 
        # the main dictionary 
        dict1[sno]= dict2 
        l = l + 1
  
  
# creating json file         
out_file = open("/home/task.json", "w") 
json.dump(dict1, out_file, indent = 4) 
out_file.close()
```

Comment: Can you not import json and use json.loads(string) ?

Comment: How? Could you help me with code if possible @JoshieWahWah

Comment: @Tahera--at the beginning of your post you have the input file having `RULE_NAME ...`. However, later you say the input file form is `>Local = 01 : SAG = any = 02 = tcp
>Local = 04 : SAG = any = any = tcp`.   Which is it?   Also, your desired output is not proper json.  You need to start with an overall dictionary, thus a **{** and have Local and bk1-2-internal as keys in that overall dictionary.

Comment: starting with text rule is just basic structure but starting with local are values that i implemented based on structure, u can consider text starting with local one, based on this need to get values for rest of the rules

Comment: @Tahera--answer shows handling of "local one".  Feedback?  One question would be do you want the numbers such as 2 which are currently shown as "2" in output to stay as numbers i.e. 2?

Comment: @Tahera--modified answer so it shows port as number rather than string when possible.

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
import os
import json

def json_from_log(path):
    '''
        Convert log to json text file as follows
        
        Steps:
            Create dictionary from log file
            Deserialize dictionary to json
            Output file same name as input but with suffix of json
    '''
    outfile = os.path.splitext(path)[0] + '.json' # same as input but with json extension
    with open(path, 'r') as fread, open(outfile, 'w') as outfile:
        result = {}
        for line in fread:
            line = line.strip()
            rule, address = line.split(':')
            rule = rule[1:-1]  # skip '>', and drop trailing space ata end of string
            address = address.lstrip()   # Drop leading space
            
            rule_id, rule_number = rule.split(' = ')
            source, destination, port, protocol = address.split(' = ')
            port = int(port) if port.isnumeric() else port
            
            # Add nested ditionaries if they don't exist for key
            result.setdefault(rule_id, {})
            result[rule_id].setdefault(rule_number, {})
            
            # Place in dictionary
            result[rule_id][rule_number].update({"SOURCE":source,
                                                  "DESTINAION": destination,
                                                  "PORT": port,
                                                  "PROTOCOL": protocol})
            
        json.dump(result, outfile, indent = 1)  # indent = 1 allows "pretty" output
```

**Usage**

```
json_from_log('test3.txt')
```

Input File: test3.txt

```
>Local = 01 : SAG = any = 02 = tcp
>Local = 04 : SAG = any = any = tcp
>bk1-2-internal = 2 : any = SoftLY = any = any
>bk1-2-internal = 28 : 119.111.126.115/18 = 129.37.164.74/30 = 112 = udpt
```

Output File: test3.json

```
{
 "Local": {
  "01": {
   "SOURCE": "SAG",
   "DESTINAION": "any",
   "PORT": 2,
   "PROTOCOL": "tcp"
  },
  "04": {
   "SOURCE": "SAG",
   "DESTINAION": "any",
   "PORT": "any",
   "PROTOCOL": "tcp"
  }
 },
 "bk1-2-internal": {
  "2": {
   "SOURCE": "any",
   "DESTINAION": "SoftLY",
   "PORT": "any",
   "PROTOCOL": "any"
  },
  "28": {
   "SOURCE": "119.111.126.115/18",
   "DESTINAION": "129.37.164.74/30",
   "PORT": 112,
   "PROTOCOL": "udpt"
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Where I'm i suppose to mention file name ie json_from_log('test3.txt')

Comment: @Tahera--'The input to json_from_log is the path to the input file. If the file is local (in the current working directory) then all you need is just the file name e.g. 'test3.txt', .  A non-local file path would be r'c:\\home\some_dir\some_file.txt'

Comment: i mean like where I'm i supposed to mention this file name and path, is it where I'm importing json code , if yes in which line. please specify

Comment: @Tahera--do you have the data to be converted in a file?  Let's say the file path was my_data_file_path.  Then all you need is `json_from_log(my_data_file_path)` after the definition of json_from_log.  You don't need the complete path if the file is in the current working directory (i.e. you can just give the file name).

Comment: No, i have 2 files in total, one where im writing the given code, other one is txt file  needed to convert data from txt to json

Comment: @Tahera--the code file contains your Python script.  So my code above would be in the code file.  The code file accesses the data file through the open(...) command.  Are you trying to use this in an environmental where the script is being run from a command line rather than a IDE?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230042/discussion-between-darrylg-and-tahera).

Comment: @Tahera--check discussion link for further comments.